# Is it possible to obtain logs to Heroku dashboard?

Tags: heroku

Is it possible to obtain the following log of Heroku dashboard?
Do I need to use add-ons?

- Login history log
- Operation history log

I'd like to acquire the period for the past year.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

> Login history log

"Login" can mean different things to different applications. Since there is no universal definition of login (especially across all of the languages that Heroku supports), this isn't something that Heroku can automatically log for you. If you want to log logins you must do it from your code.

Heroku [captures the `stderr` and `stdout` streams from your application](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/logging#writing-to-your-log) in its own logs.

The same applies to

> Operation history log

but more so. An "operation" is much more generic than a "login", and Heroku has no way of knowing what it should log from your application. It also doesn't modify or otherwise instrument your code.

> I'd like to acquire the period for the past year. Is it possible?

Even if these logs were automatically generated by Heroku, or you're already outputting the relevant information to `stderr` or `stdout`, you can't go back that far retroactively.

Heroku [only keeps the last 1,500 lines from your logs and they expire after a week](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/logging#log-history-limits). If you want to keep more lines, or keep them for more than a week, you can use a [logging add-on](https://elements.heroku.com/addons/#logging) or set up a [log drain](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/log-drains).

Unfortunately, both of these options will only help with new log entries. There is no way to retrieve past logs beyond Heroku's limits described above.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
What I would like to ask is login to heroku dashboard (heroku administration).

Comment: @itsuka, the logs that exist are available via the dashboard, but that doesn't change any of what I wrote. If you want to log specific things like logins and arbitrary operations you'll have to do that in your code and you can't go back beyond 1,500 lines or one week.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this will help you

```
 heroku logs
```

And to tail the logs live

```
heroku logs -t
```

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/logging#view-logs

```
$ heroku run rails c
File.open('log/production.log', 'r').each_line { |line| puts line }
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
What I would like to ask is login to heroku dashboard (heroku administration).

Comment: Here's the link https://dashboard.heroku.com/apps after login to heroku